# entity_autocomplete attached via #ajax callback doesn't work

Tags: 9

I'm serving an entity_autocomplete field via #ajax callback when a checkbox in the form is unchecked.

The entity_autocomplete field shows but there is no autocomplete attached to it.

Here is how I attached it from within ajax callback:

```php
$form['url_301'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-output">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
];
$form['url_301'] = EntityAutocomplete::processEntityAutocomplete($form['url_301'], $form_state, $form);

return $form['url_301'];
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

The `entity_autocomplete` field should be prepared/set within `hook_form_alter()`, not within `ajax_callback()`

And it should be returned within `ajax_callback()`.

Here is an example:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $status = $form_state->getValue('status')['value'];

  if ($status === 0) {

    $form['url'] = [
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#target_type' => 'node',
      '#title' => t('My autocomplete field'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-output">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

  }

  $form['output'] = [
    '#markup' => 'Output',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-output">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => 100,
  ];

  $form['status']['widget']['value']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => '_my_ajax_callback',
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-output',
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => 'Processing...',
    ],
  ];
}

function _my_ajax_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $status = $form_state->getValue('status')['value'];

  if ($status == 0) {
    return $form['url'];
  }
  else {
    return [
      '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-output">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];
  }
}
```